# C++ String Comparison "Good Luck" > "Good Bye"

Tags: c++

I am comparing two strings "Good Luck" > "Good Bye" in c++.  Shouldn't the boolean result be true? The 'L' is greater than the 'B' The blank space between the words is one whitespace.

However, I am getting false with run the code.

Do you know why? Below is my code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    bool result = "Good Luck" > "Good Bye!";

    cout << result;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're comparing pointers.

Comment: Distinguish C-string and `std::string`.

Comment: That's `const char*`

Comment: This is what the documentation says - s1 > s2 : A string s1 is greater than s2 string, if either, length of s1 is longer than s2 or first mismatched character is larger

Comment: @Avi but you are *not* comparing `std::string`s. You are comparing `const char *`s.

Comment: @Avi Whatever document you are reading, make sure what you read is relevant to what you use. I rephrase: String literal is not `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing `char*`s, which is just comparing the memory addresses that the strings live at.

Comment: The documentation differs -- s1 > s2 : A string s1 is greater than s2 string, if either, length of s1 is longer than s2 or first mismatched character is larger

Comment: @Avi: That's the documentation for `std::string`, which you are not using.

Comment: @Avi I repeat: Distinguish C-string and `std::string`.